# Should I call release on a removed child?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, cocos2d-iphone

```
MyClass *var = [[MyClass alloc]initWithSomeNumber:15];
[self addChild:var];
[self removeChild:var cleanup:YES];
```

Do I have to call `release` for `var`? Or does the `removeChild` method already takes care of such? Is there a way to create `var` without having to use `alloc`? I heard that there is a class method for nodes called `node`. But it doesn't accept parameters (and as you can see I need to pass the integer 15).

Comment: yes, since you use alloc, this increments the ref counter by one, therefore you own the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is one of the rules defined in the [Memory management policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

> You own any object you create

You use `alloc` to allocate space for `var`, which will set the `var` reference counter to 1. NO matter how many other objects claim ownership after this (by sending`retain`) you must send `release` on `var` to decrement the reference counter by 1. Otherwise, the reference counter will never reach 0 which means that the memory used for `var` will never be deallocated, i.e. end up with a memory leak.

```
MyClass *var = [[MyClass alloc]initWithSomeNumber:15]; // ref count = 1
[self addChild:var]; // ref count ++
[self removeChild:var cleanup:YES]; //ref count--
//ref count is 1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using ARC, yes, you need to release it. `self` will retain child when you add it and release it when you remove it, which still leaves the implicit retain from your alloc/init call.

Answer (score 1):

Use ARC this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) will help you